# "Dictionary nest" in C#?

Tags: c#

Im beginner in C# and I´m trying to do the following:

I created a Dictionary: `_innerProducts = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

then another dictionary to store the first one on it: `_KitProducts = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();`

The first one (_`innerProducts`) contains about 15 products atributes that I collected from and .xml file, and the TKey its the product code.

after collect all the atributes I call:

```
_KitProducts.Add(_innerProducts["cProd"], _innerProducts);
```

When I watch this via debug, its works fine, as I can see:

[image: Before Clear]

The problem is that I cannot add another group of atributes using the same TKey as the first `_innerProducts` "cProd", so inside the foreach I put one `_innerProducts.Clear();` at the end.

The problem is when I Clear it, it clear not only the current _innerProducts, it clear the TValue of the _KitProducts too:

[image: After Clear]

Im not sure if this is because of those "by reference" and not "by value" lecture that I read (remember I´m at very beginning), so what should I do in this case?

It will be a lot of those cases, I know that I will need to store it (but I still didnt learn Entity Framework, working on it), while that, Im just storing in the Dictionary to learning purposes.

Thanks and sorry for the english, isnt my main language.

Comment: Can you share the code (as code in the question) you are using to do this.

Comment: Well, it's not "by value" vs "by reference" in terms of parameter passing, but yes, it's because the dictionary holds a *reference* to the values. I suggest you read http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html It's not particularly clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but understanding the way C# works in terms of objects and references is *really* important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding the value to the outer dictionary, both `_innerProducts` and the value of the outer dictionary entry refer to the same object:

```
             +-----------------------+
             | your inner dictionary |
             +-----------------------+
                ^          ^
                |          |
      _innerProducts      value in the outer dictionary entry
```

When executing `_innerProducts.Clear()`, you empty that dictionary with the following result:

```
             +-----------------------+
             |    empty dictionary   |
             +-----------------------+
                ^          ^
                |          |
      _innerProducts      value in the outer dictionary entry
```

---

Thus, instead of emptying the *existing* instance, create a new instance, i.e., replace

```
_innerProducts.Clear();     // "a.DoSomething()" operates on the object referenced by a
```

with

```
_innerProducts = new Dictionary<string, string>();    // "a = ..." defines which object a refers to
```

That results in the following situation:

```
   +-----------------------+    +-----------------------+
   |   a new, empty dict.  |    | your inner dictionary |
   +-----------------------+    +-----------------------+
                         ^          ^
                         |          |
               _innerProducts      value in the outer dictionary entry
```

That way, you don't modify the existing inner dictionary, but instead let the variable `_innerProducts` point to a new one.

Even simpler and better, if possible: Move the declaration of `_innerProducts` *inside* the loop that you use to fill `_KitProducts`. That will ensure that each loop iteration gets its own instance of the inner dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in such detail, so I just not only solve the problem (changing .Clear() to new dictionary) but also understood why that happened!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid changing your data inside the main dictionary - just put the copies of inner dictionaries

```
var key = _innerProducts["cProd"];
var value = new Dictionary<string, string>(_innerProducts);
_KitProducts.Add(key, value);
```